# How do i figure out what mystery Postgres databases are from my Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, service, datatable

I use Aiven.io to manage a PSQL server, inside has multiple databases! Im using it from my rails app, so my rails app uses *xxx_production*, *xxx_development* etc.. But i dont remember creating *xxx_optimization* or *metrics* databases.  The *metrics* one in particular is 50GB (My *xxx_production* is only 11GB so this is costing me a lot of extra money)

Is there any way to figure out who created these or why? My suspicion is there is some GEM im using in my rails app that could have created it to keep track of things? No idea what these databases are, and i would delete them but I do want to know what they are so i make sure im not breaking anything.

[image: Aiven Screeshot]

Thanks!

Comment: The metric db should be aiven's.

Comment: I asked customer service and they insist its not theirs